# Get view for inherited view controller from storyboard

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have two classes: `AViewController : UIViewController` and `BViewController : AViewController`.

When I use AViewController.xib, I can create instance `BViewController` **from one common xib**:

```
BViewController *bVC = [[BViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AViewController" bundle:nil];    
[self presentViewController:bVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Storyboard can instantiate `AViewController`:

```
AViewController *aVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AViewController"];
```

How can I instantiate `BViewController` from Storyboard with view with identifier 'AViewController'?

Comment: you mean, using the one with identifier AViewController?

Comment: Yep, it is. One UI-view in Storyboard — two classes in code.

Comment: @Sound Blaster: Your setup is not really clear you have to be more exact. When you instantiate a storyboard scene with identity @"AViewController" it has no any connection with any kind of xib/nib! But you could instantiate a view controller and it has a xib and in the xib you could instantiate several new UIVieControllers.

Comment: @BootMaker you didn't understand my target, i think. "When you instantiate a storyboard scene with identity" — storyboard return me a pointer to a instance of some strong defined class inherited from UIViewController. I want to use ONE interface from Storyboard with some different subclasses of base UIViewController. I can't subclass a returned by storyboard view controller instance at the runtime, and i can't bring UI from that instance... 8(